# CreateJS object visibility

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs

i hope someone can help.

I have a game in CreateJS working fine, added functionality for a pause button, also working fine, except the pause button isn't visible, but all my other objects are :( If I click where I know the pause button is the functionality works but I just can't see the button.

Code below: What happens is onclick of my character, it goes into function pauseGame (this is working, pausing the game.). This should make the pause.visible = true. I think it does maybe, because if I click the pause (the co-ordinates where I know it exists) the game restarts (goes into function startGame), the problem is when I click to Pause the game, it pauses, but I can't see my button which says 'game paused, click here to resume game' but if I click it the game restarts. Is this to do with zindex placing or something else causing the object to be not visible?

```
function pauseGame(event) 
{
   if(exportRoot.gameOver.visible == false) 
   {
exportRoot.pause.visible = true;
    console.log("Pausing");
    inPlay = false;
    }
}
function startGame(event) 
{
   if (exportRoot.gameOver.visible == false) 
   {
    inPlay = true;
    exportRoot.pause.visible = false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Few things you should check:

```
- Opacity, just try: console.log(exportRoot.pause.alpha); if it's not 1, something might be wrong.
- Visibility: console.log(exportRoot.pause.visible), if false, something is wrong.
- last thing: try addChild(exportRoot.pause) to see if the button is under some other element.
```